# Find the collection name from document._id in meteor (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

From the looks of the syntax for handling mongodb related things in meteor it seems that you always need to know the `collection's name` to `update, insert, remove or anything` to the document.

What I am wondering is if it's possible to get the `collection's name` from the `_id` field of a document in meteor.

Meaning if you have a document with the `_id` equal to `TNTco3bHzoSFMXKJT`. Now knowing the `_id` of the document you want to find which `collection` the `document` is located in. Is this possible through meteor's implementation of mongodb or vanilla mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by doing a `findOne` on all of the collections:

```js
var collectionById = function(id) {
  return _.find(_.keys(this), function(name) {
    if (this[name] instanceof Meteor.Collection) {
      if (this[name].findOne(id)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

I tested this on both the client and the server and it seemed to work when run in the global context.

Answer (score 0):

As taken from the [official docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection):

> **idGeneration** String
>
> The method of generating the _id fields of new documents in this collection. Possible values:
>
> 'STRING': random strings
>   'MONGO': random Meteor.Collection.ObjectID values
>
> The default id generation technique is 'STRING'.

Your best option would be to `insert` records within a pseudo transaction where the second step is to take the `id` and collection name to feed it into a reference collection. Then, you can do your lookups from that.

It would be pretty costly, though to construct your `find`'s but might be a pattern worthwhile exploring if you are building an app where your users will be creating arbitrary data patterns.